# How to break out a loop in a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

**hi how can I break out of the for loop ? I want to be able to break out of it in the callback in the if statement**

I want this program to create a folder in the given directory and every time it throws an error I want it to change the folder name and add a number to it so when it says that the folder already exists, It'll create a unique folder name until it doesn't throw an error.

> I will check for the error code later help me solve this first

```
const path = require('path');

function folder(folderName) {

    for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        let pathNumber = i;
        let fullPath = folderName + pathNumber;

        fs.mkdir(path.join("D:", fullPath), (err) => {

            if (!err) {
                return; // I want to break out of the loop here
            }

        })
    }
}

folder("folder");
```

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal That other question is not relevant to the asynchronous callback used here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write the code that way because the `for` loop will already be done before any of the `fs.mkdir()` callbacks are called.  They are asynchronous and happen LATER.

If you want to execute one iteration of the loop, including the `fs.mkdir()` before moving on to any other, then you can use `async/await` with [`fs.promises.mkdir()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesmkdirpath-options).

Here's what a solution could look like with `fs.promises.mkdir()`.  I've also added error handling for the case where all 10 sub-dir names you're trying already exist.

```
async function folder(folderName) {
    let lastError;
    for (let pathNumber = 1; pathNumber <= 10; pathNumber++) {
        let fullPath = path.join("D:", folderName + pathNumber);
        try {
            await fs.promises.mkdir(fullPath);
            return fullPath;
        } catch(e) {
            lastError = e;
            // ignore error so we keep trying other numbers
        }
    }
    throw lastError;
}

folder("folder").then(fullPath => {
   console.log(`dir created: ${fullPath}`);
}).catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler without await

```js
const numFolders = 10,
folders = Array.from(Array(numFolders), (_,i) => `folder${i+1}`), len = folder.length;
let cnt = 0;

const makeFolder = () => {
  if (cnt >= len) return; // stop because done
  fs.mkdir(path.join("D:", fullPath), (err) => {
  if (err) {
     makeFolder(); // only call again if error
  }
  cnt++
}
makeFolder()
```